# Toggle one div from two clicks if untoggled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I have a comment section that is initially hidden, and would be revealed by a link on the comment count and/or a link to add comments.

I would like for the comment section to open by either link, but not close if its already opened.

```
$( "#commentsToggle").click(function() {
  $( "#comments" ).toggle( "fast" );
  return false;
});
$( ".comment-add a").click(function() {
  $( "#comments" ).toggle( "fast" );
  return false;
});
```

See the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/pQ2np/

Thanks

**EDIT**: The '#commentsToggle' should be able to toggle (hide) the comments if open, the '.comment-add a' should only show, not hide as it opens an ajax comment form.

This is the code solves my need:

```
$( "#commentsToggle").click(function() {
  $( "#comments" ).toggle( "fast" );
  return false;
});
$( ".comment-add a").click(function() {
  $( "#comments" ).show( "fast" );
  return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pQ2np/6/

Comment: I thought the jsfiddle worked fine... Maybe I'm missing something? :)

Comment: change `toggle` to `show`

Comment: Should the section close if the same link is clicked on?

Comment: Actually this is an excellent question, the '#commentsToggle' should be able to toggle (hide) the comments if open, the '.comment-add a' should only show, not hide as it opens an ajax comment form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them to remain open. use `show()` instead of `toggle()`.

```
$( "#commentsToggle").click(function() {
  $( "#comments" ).show( "fast" );
  return false;
});
$( ".comment-add a").click(function() {
  $( "#comments" ).show( "fast" );
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put both selectors into one function and pass true as the first parameter to showOrhide as referenced in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide).

```
$( "#commentsToggle, .comment-add a").click(function() {
  $( "#comments" ).toggle( true );
  return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pQ2np/3/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pQ2np/5/) plus enhancements. Below is the gist of it:

```
$( "#commentsToggle, .comment-add a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $comments = $("#comments");
    if ($comments.is(":visible")) {
        return;
    }

    $comments.show("fast");

});
```

**UPDATE:** I missed the fact that if you "show" the links again but want to prevent them from being toggled, you only need to use the `.show()` method. No need for toggle if your intention is for the comments section to appear once and remain open.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the code in the following link (I have updated your own).

I am not sure why to use toggle and not show. But generally you can check the css display attribute because this is what is used by jquery events.

```
$( "#commentsToggle").click(function() {
    if ($( "#comments" ).css("display") != "block")
      $( "#comments" ).toggle( "fast" );
  return false;
});
$( ".comment-add a").click(function() {
    if ($( "#comments" ).css("display") != "block")
          $( "#comments" ).toggle( "fast" );
  return false;
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8WgCR/)

Is that you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You could use .show() instead of .toggle(), or you could add "true" as one of the parameters:

```
$( "#commentsToggle").click(function() {
  $( "#comments" ).toggle( "fast", true );
  return false;
});
$( ".comment-add a").click(function() {
  $( "#comments" ).toggle( "fast", true );
  return false;
});
```

Using false instead of true will hide the elements, so using a variable in there could come in useful later.